90s/00s Gang movie. Four friends upset a gang boss who offers them a "last request" each
It's an urban movie, 90's or early 2000's, probably a C or B rank. Same type as Hot Boyz and Blue Hill Avenue. One of the characters is nicknamed Smooth.
Four friends somehow offend a crime boss. The boss invites them to a party and attempts to satisfy one desire before killing them to be polite. One friend wants to try all the best weed, another's a fat guy wants to have sex (he gets shot right afterward), Smooth dominates a strong independent woman, the main character saves the rest of his friends by claiming his desire wasn't satisfied because the woman asked him to play cards. He says his desire's to be spared so the boss lets them go but they have to pay money.
So they rob a drug dealer in his apt. complex who turns out to be an undercover cop. The weed smoker loses his cool and kills Smooth and makes the main guy help him dump Smooth's body in a dumpster. Then he attempts to kill the main guy and the undercover cop and flee with the money. Somehow the Main guy lives and the crime boss dies; I think the weed smoker ends up trying to flee to Jamaica.

I think you're looking for Dough Boys from 2009.

For the "Dough Boys" every day is a struggle to survive. Determined to make something of their lives, these four friends work any hustle no matter how risky. But when they bite off more than they can chew, their loyal bond is tested as they fight to stay alive. Now, the rules of the street that they live by are the very rules that could destroy them.

They run afoul of a rich gangster, one of them is called Smooth and another is chubby. I wish I could tell you more, but the film is pretty obscure. Here's the DVD cover, where you can see the 4 boys:

